# Constrained optimization: When are the Lagrange multipliers bounded?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

In some texts I have seen arguments for the fact that the Lagrange multipliers of a constrained optimization problem remain bounded. Are there general conditions for that fact?

In particular,

Let a mathematical program:
\begin{align}
    &\mathrm{min}~ f(x)\\
    &\mathrm{s.t.}~ g_i(x) \leq 0, ~\forall i\in I\\
    &\mathrm{~~~~~~}~ h_j(x) \leq 0, ~\forall j\in J.
\end{align}

The lagrangian function of the constrained optimization problem is the following:
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L}(x, \lambda, \mu) = f(x) + \langle \lambda, g(x) \rangle + \langle \mu, h(x) \rangle.
\end{equation}

Under which conditions do we know that $\| \lambda \|_2 < \infty$?